# React dom , getElementByID

Tags: reactjs, getelementbyid, react-dom, react-ref

how can we set normal DOM manipulation into react DOM

here is my code

had tried in different since I got continues error as

Comment: looks like there is no element with id `stock-prize`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the statment is correct but you need to use getElementById after render use the function useeffect to do it like the bellow:

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
  
let ws = new WebSocket('wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/etheur@trade');
let stockPriceElement = document.getElementById('stock-prize');


ws.onmessage = (event)=>{
    let stockObject = JSON.parse(event.data);
    stockPriceElement.innerText = parseFloat(stockObject.p).toFixed(2);
}
return () => ws.close(); //closes connection on unmmount
  }, [])
```

let me know if it's working

Comment: no it doesn't

returns error like a uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
    at resolveDispatcher (react.development.js:1476:13)
    at Object.useEffect (react.development.js:1519:20)

Answer (score 1):

DOM is not able to find this element

```
let stockPriceElement = document.getElementById('stock-prize');
```

stockPriceElement is not defined, try to console log it .

please share codesandbox link so that i can help you more

Answer (score 0):

1. You should never update DOM using DOM manipulation in React.
2. Use states to manage data. If data is somewhere else in the component tree, use `context` API or global states.
3. The error you are getting is because when your code executes the target element has not been rendered. Use `ref` to access DOM nodes. More about ref [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)